# How can I save a layer from WMS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

I´m using a layer from this WMS (http://gis.invemar.org.co/arcgis/rest/services/SIGMA/MANGLARES_COLOMBIA/MapServer). However, I can´t save the layer in my computer, I can´t make geoprocesses or any other action. 
How can I download this layer on my computer? Either in .shp or .tiff format (I only manage to download it in .lyr but I don't have ArcGIS and in .kmz but it doesn't open in QGIS).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything with WMS: it's a service exposing image not features (vector things). Most of the time when you have WMS, you have other services more or less hidden. In ArcGIS World, the equivalent of WFS is "ArcGIS feature layer". So, to get vector you can process, you need to find on the server the "right" web service. In QGIS, it means you will add an ArcGIS feature layer.

Go to menu "Layer" > "Add Layer" > "Add ArcGIS Feature Server".

Here, create a new connexion with Name "Manglare colombia" and add for URL the following `http://gis.invemar.org.co/arcgis/rest/services/SIGMA/MANGLARES_COLOMBIA/MapServer`.

Then click OK and now select the new connexion and click "Connect". You will see a layer with name "MANGLARE".

Click on it and do "Add". Wait (not fast) to get the layer as features.

Now, you can save locally as a vector layer doing a right click on the layer and choosing "Export". With this last operation, you don't need to use the remote connexion now to work (slow, could fail)

See below a screenshot of the last part

[image: Illustrate export from remote ArcGIS Server]

Comment: It worked perfectly. Really, really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The wms is an image, you can download in some formats, you have to do this:

1. Open de URL.

   http://gis.invemar.org.co/arcgis/rest/services/SIGMA/MANGLARES_COLOMBIA/MapServer
2. On the final of the page, select **Export map**

[image]

3. You can choose the format of the image, like this:

[image]

4. Finally, select Format: Image and **Export Map image (Get)**

[image]

5. This will show you an image, only you have to right click and save as.

When you do that, you will open the image in QGIS and you have to georeference the image, in this case.